# How do I move a Google Analytic property to another account?

Tags: google-analytics

I've got a GA account that contains several "accounts" and "properties", all under the same email address. The set up looks a little similar to this:

- My overall Google Account (abc@gmail.com)

  - My Sites (account)

    - example.com (property)
    - subdomain.example.com (property)
    - anothersite.com (property)
  - Client Sites (account)

    - theirsite.com (property)

And so on.

I've created a new account called "example.com related sites" and I'd like to move example.com and subdomain.example.com into this new account.

But I can't find an easy way to do it, without possibly deleting my properties and re-creating them, then updating my site to use the new tracking code.

How can I move properties between accounts without deleting them?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no way to move properties from one GA account into another.

**Update**: September 10, 2016

Now there is a way to move GA properties between different accounts:

[image]

[image]

Comment: So my suspicions were correct? I need to delete my properties, re-create them and update my site to use the new tracking code?

Comment: That is correct, although I would hang onto the existing properties and views first just in case, and also to see historical data.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I've renamed my original properties and created some new ones. Cheers :)